# Data volumes location in Docker Desktop (Windows)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a project in docker that works without an issue on MacOS. But I wasn't able to get it working on Windows (WSL2).

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows. (Windows 11)

```
Server: Docker Desktop 4.26.1 (131620)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
```

I have multiple projects (images) and a composer project in the same directory. Composer project starts up all of these projects.

I just can't figure out how to locate the data volumes. It looks like the source of the problem is the usage of $PWD variable in the configuration. By default, this causes to get `PWD variable is not set` warning and results in;

> Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount
> /docker-volumes/local-mongo-data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/composer_-local-mongo-data/_data,
> flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

But I tried to;

- define PWD variable in `.env` file and set it to `.`.
- change the usage of variable as `${PWD}`.
- replace `/` with `\`
- get rid of the variable and manually prefix the directories with something like `E:\Projects\composer\docker-volumes`, `/E/Projects/composer/docker-volumes` etc.
- or prefix the volume directories with wsl directory `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`

But I couldn't get it to work.

Part of the `docker-compose.yml` looks like this in the composer project;

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:15672"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - "local-rabbit-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq"
    pull_policy: always
  redis:
    image: "marketplace.gcr.io/google/redis6"
    command:
      - /etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - local-redis-data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    pull_policy: always
  api:
    image: api
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - mongodb
      - backend
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env.api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ../api/src:/usr/src/app/src
    command: yarn start:dev
  mongodb:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:5.0.8"
    env_file:
      - .env.mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - "local-mongo-data:/bitnami"
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - db
volumes:
  local-rabbit-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/docker-volumes/local-rabbit-data
      o: bind
  local-mongo-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/docker-volumes/local-mongo-data
      o: bind
  local-redis-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/docker-volumes/local-redis-data
      o: bind
```

The directory to navigate data volumes in the file explorer:

```
\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes
```

My projects on Windows is in this directory:

```
E:\Projects\
```

Directory of the volumes in the composer project:

```
E:\Projects\composer\docker-volumes
```

Could you help me to figure out how to set directories for volumes?

Comment: Instead of `$PWD/docker-volumes/local-rabbit-data`, can you do `./docker-volumes/local-rabbit-data`? Compose can use relative paths, unlike 'raw' Docker.

Comment: @HansKilian thank you for the comment, the error becomes `Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount ./docker-volumes/local-rabbit-data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/composer-local-rabbit-data/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory`